# Homogeneity and $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, weak-derivatives

Let $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n \backslash \{0\} )$ be homogeneous of degree $m\in \mathbb{R}$: $f(tx)=t^mf(x)$ for $t>0$ and $x\neq 0$. When can we say $f \in L^p(B_r(0))$?

Here is the motivation: we know $|x|^m \in W^{1,p} (B_r(0))$ iff $m+\frac{n}{p}>1$. Can we conclude the same result for general homogeneous functions?

Comment: Note $f$ is bounded on the unit sphere (by $M$, say). Thus $|f(x)| = |x|^m |f(x/|x|)| \le |x|^m M$.